# How to use a for each loop with a multi-dimensional array in C++

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, c++-cli

Okay, so first off you should note that I am using visual studio 2010.  Anyways, I am getting a very weird error in my for each loop that doesn't make any sense to me.

```
BYTE CPUKeys[][0x10] =
{
    {0x28,0x53,0x71,0xD9,0x7B,0x47,0xCC,0x50,0xAF,0x45,0x8D,0xB3,0xED,0x53,0x22,0x13},//Randy//encrypted
    {0x6E,0x38,0xB0,0xEF,0x6E,0x96,0x20,0x16,0xE5,0xCA,0x4B,0xE9,0x23,0x4E,0xC6,0xA5},//Josh//encrypted
    {0x95,0x2C,0x20,0x98,0xF9,0x99,0x28,0x0F,0xEE,0xA7,0x8F,0x48,0x58,0x01,0xB7,0x07},//Falcon//encrypted
    {0x64,0xDC,0x1E,0xFA,0xD2,0xAE,0x57,0x6C,0x0B,0xD0,0x39,0x6A,0x13,0x2C,0x91,0xE0},//Justin//encrypted
    {0x8D,0x82,0x6D,0x71,0x82,0xDC,0x83,0x8F,0x79,0x51,0xB8,0x7C,0x1F,0xC1,0xBF,0xD4},//Bypass//encrypted
    {0x27,0xF2,0xA7,0xF3,0xE2,0xDC,0x01,0x19,0x17,0xF4,0x11,0xFE,0xE9,0xB5,0x0C,0x2C},//Surge//encrypted
    {0x6D,0x7C,0x86,0x9A,0x6A,0xE1,0xD4,0x10,0x76,0x16,0x11,0x7C,0xED,0xB3,0x4D,0x56},//Noel//encrypted
    {0x3D,0x6C,0x88,0x8C,0x9D,0x3A,0xA5,0x40,0x64,0xDF,0xDF,0x8D,0x94,0xFD,0x28,0xF1},//XexRgh//encrypted
    {0x06,0x0D,0x8C,0xB6,0xB6,0x6D,0x29,0xD7,0x41,0xE1,0x13,0x35,0x84,0x80,0x68,0x31}//Zoobzy//encrypted
};
```

Alright so there is my multi-dimensional BYTE array.

```
for each(BYTE ID[0x10] in CPUKeys)
{
```

And there is my for each loop.  The weird thing that is happening with it is my error that I am getting on ID.  The error states: 'for each' iterator type "BYTE[16]" is not compatible with element type "BYTE[16]".  Any idea why it might say this?  What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `for each(BYTE ID[0x10] in CPUKeys)` is not a valid C++ construct, show the exact statement & errors

Comment: My compiler (VS 2005) shows a different error: `for each statement cannot operate on variables of type 'unsigned char [9][16]'`, so maybe what you want is impossible...

Comment: This is the entire function of what I am using, sorry for the confusion. Edit: apparently enter does not indent to the next line on a comment.  Also, it was too long to comment anyways :(

Comment: You mean `c++/cli` right? (It's rather a different beast to `c++`)

Comment: @user3765064 Just a wild guess: maybe `BYTE (&ID)[0x10]` works? (I cannot check it myself)

Comment: BYTE (&ID)[0x10] seems to work, at least it fixes my error.  Thanks a BUNCH!  (The real question is, will it fix my problem where my modified xbox console black screened...?) lol

Comment: Edit: I can't build it.  Now it says cannot convert from BYTE to BYTE(&)[16]......

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works:

```
for(auto& rows: CPUKeys)// Iterating over rows
{
    for(auto& elem: rows)
    {
        // iterate every row's column
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support for range loops, but I haven't used it for a long time though.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know there is not foeach loop in c++.
Use two for loops instead. Something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j)
   {
     BYTE value = CPUKeys[i][j];
   }
}
```

Comment: There's syntax for foreach loop in `C++11`

Comment: OP uses Visual Studio 2010; `for each` seems to be a language extension specific to that compiler

Comment: for(int KeyNum = 1;KeyNum < 10;KeyNum++)
 {
  if(!memcmp(Cpu,CPUKeys[KeyNum],0x10))
  {       //this black screens the xbox console, though.  It seems to do what you are saying, though.  Any thoughts on what might be wrong with this?